# C# - How to set builder.Property().HasComment dynamically in a model in Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to apply `builder.Property(_ => _.[DYNAMIC_FIELD_NAME]).HasComment("Some comment")` data to all of the properties that have `Description` attribute in a model. So far here's my attempt using reflection:

```
public class User : TableFieldsBase, IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        var tableName = this.GetType().Name;
        builder.ToTable(tableName);
        
        var props = GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            var descriptionAttr = this.GetAttributeFrom<DescriptionAttribute>(prop.Name);
            if(descriptionAttr != null)
            {
                builder.Property(t => EF.Property<object>(t, prop.Name)).HasComment(descriptionAttr.Description);
            }
        }
    }

    [Description("This is the username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I'm looping through all of the properties of the model and extracting their description text. For example `Username` has a description attribute that I wanna use to save that in the "comment" field within my database. The issue here I'm not sure how to apply the property dynamically within `builder.Property` method. Maybe I'm looking at it in a wrong way?

This is the error I'm getting when I run this code:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentException
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'The expression 't => Property(t, value(Backend.Classes.Api.Avpf.Core.Models.User+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).prop.Name)' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ExpressionExtensions.GetPropertyAccess(LambdaExpression propertyAccessExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.Property[TProperty](Expression`1 propertyExpression)
   at Backend.Classes.Api.Avpf.Core.Models.User.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in Models\User.cs:line 38
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong with the code shown? (Besides `EF.Property` returning the value of a property, and not a reference to it?)

Comment: `builder.Property` has an overload that takes a `MemberInfo`, which should be `prop`...

Comment: @NetMage - It throws an error. check the updated question

Comment: Did you try just using `prop` by itself? NM - I think I was looking at the wrong type for `builder`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [`Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.property?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_Property_System_String_) method overload with `string propertyName` argument:

```
builder.Property(prop.Name)
    .HasComment(descriptionAttr.Description);
```